# .htaccess redirect to https and www. if enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I want to configure my .htaccess file in a manner where it will do these two things:

- ALWAYS make sure `www.` is appended (even for subdomains like  so: `www.sub.example.com`).
- OPTIONALLY add `https://` if it is enabled.

I preferably (if possible) want to do this in one rewrite rule, currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So how do I make the `s` of `https://` optional in the same rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rule to redirect `https` , `non-https` and `non-www` requests to `www` with a single redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This is doing a 302 Temporary redirect.  If you want a 301 permanent redirect, change the `R` flag to `R=301` .

Comment: this doesn't enforce https when it is enabled though

Comment: I used curl instead of a browser.

Comment: Okay, could you please post an example of the url that is not working for you?

Comment: `curl http://www.ssltest.com -k` just gives me the page, without a 301/302. (`ssltest.com` is pointed at the correct IP via host file, because I do not own the the domain.)

Comment: Try removing or commenting out the the first Rewrite Condition      

  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\`